# Function in stateless component is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my below code it is giving an error: CreateParticipant.jsx:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: handleInputChangeName is not defined

I could not understand what is the problem. I have already defined the function, then also it is giving such an error.

Can someone please help me in finding out the problem.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const CreateParticipant = () => {

  const [name, setname] = useState([])
  const [email, setemail] = useState([])

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    if(event.target.name === "name"){
      setname(event.target.value)
    }
    else if(event.target.name === "email"){
      setemail(event.target.value)
    }
  }

  async function createPostRequest(event) {
    // console.log('this.state', this.state);
    const statepost = { name, email }
    await fetch('/api/v1/participants', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(statepost),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }).then((response) => {
      alert('Post created successfully');
      location.href = '/';
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    createPostRequest()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>New Post</h3>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='name'
          value={name}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>email: </label>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='email'
          value={email}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
      {/* <div>
          <label>created_at: </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='created_at'
            value={created_at}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
        </div> */}
      <button onClick={this.createPostRequest}>Create</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateParticipant;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in a class component where `functionName = () => {}` is valid, a function component is just that - a function. You need either `var`, `let` or `const`:

```
const handleInputChangeName = (event) => {
  if(event.target.name === "name"){
    setname(event.target.value)
  }
  else if(event.target.name === "email"){
    setemail(event.target.value)
  }
}
```

Additionally, the `this.` is not needed since the functions are in the scope of the same function, e.g.:

```
onChange={handleInputChange}
// ...
onClick={createPostRequest}
```

Comment: Then how to use it in return()

Comment: But now I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPostRequest' of undefined`

Comment: @jsav You need to remove `this.` from that as well

Answer (score 2):

Modules are always run in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) where implicit globals are forbidden.

You need to **explicitly** declare the variable (with `const` (or `let` or `var`)).

```
const handleInputChangeName = (event) => {
```

Comment: Then how to use it in return()

Comment: The same way you use any variable. With its name! (and no `this` because it isn't a property of an object!)